# Swift - passing data from VC to detail VC with Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I'm totally new to Swift well I have a View Controller, where a uitableview of data is being fetched from the Firestore and I want to send this data from View Controller to detail View Controller. I mean, when a cell in View Controller is clicked, detail View Controller shows such as name, description from Firestore.. is there anyone to help me?

here's HospitalViewController.Swift :

```
class HospitalViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

struct HospitalData {
    var Name: String = ""
    var Image: String = ""
    var Region: String = ""
    
    func getDic() -> [String:String] {
        let dic = [
            "Name": self.Name,
            "Image": self.Image,
            "Region": self.Region
        ]
        return dic
    }
}

var hospitalArray: Array<HospitalData> = []
    
    @IBOutlet weak var hospitalTableView: UITableView!
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
            
            hospitalTableView.delegate = self
            hospitalTableView.dataSource = self
        }

@IBAction func onBtnRead(_ sender: UIButton) {
    getValueFromList()
}
func getValueFromList() {
    hospitalArray.removeAll() 
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    db.collection("Hospital").getDocuments() { 
        (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let error = err {
            print("fail", error)
        }else{
            print("success")
            
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                
                let dataDic = document.data() as NSDictionary
                let Name = dataDic["Name"] as? String ?? ""
                print("Name:", Name)
                let Image = dataDic["Image"] as? String ?? ""
                print("Image:", Image)
                let Region = dataDic["Region"] as? String ?? ""
                print("Region:", Region)
                
                var hospital = HospitalData()
                hospital.Name = Name
                hospital.Image = Image
                hospital.Region = Region
                self.hospitalArray.append(hospital)
                
            }
            
            self.hospitalTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func setValueIntoList() {
    var hospital = HospitalData()
    hospital.Name = "SUN Hospital"
    hospital.Image = "hospital.png"
    hospital.Region = "Seoul"
    let dic = hospital.getDic()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
    ref = db.collection("Hospital").addDocument(data: dic) {
        err in
        if let error = err {
            print("fail", error)
        }else{
            print("success", ref!.documentID)
        }
    }
    
}

// mark: datasource
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.hospitalArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = hospitalTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "hosptialTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HospitalTableViewCell
    
    let hospitalStruct = self.hospitalArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.labelName.text = hospitalStruct.Name
    cell.labelRegion.text = hospitalStruct.Region
    cell.hospitalImageView.image = UIImage(named: "hospital.png")
    
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To navigate from one `viewcontroller` to others you can use the basic push navigation as bellow

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "YOUR_STORYBOARD", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR_VC_IDENTIFIER") as? YOUR_VC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Now to pass data from one view to the `viewcontroller` you would like to move you have to declare a variable on the `viewcontroller` you would like to move.

i.e
You need to have a variable in your detail vc.

hospital_detail_vc.swift

`var hospitalData: HospitalData?`

Now you need to pass the data/variable as below through the navigation in your `TableView`'s method `didSelectRowAt` as below.

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "YOUR_STORYBOARD", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR_VC_IDENTIFIER") as? YOUR_VC 
viewController.hospitalData = self.hospitalArray[indexPath.row]
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: nice to know you Maulik! thanks for answering well I tried to copy them on my code but It doesn't work well meh

there are errors like "Use of undeclared type 'HospitalData'",  "Value of type 'HospitalDescriptionViewController?' has no member 'hospitalData'", "Value of optional type 'HospitalDescriptionViewController?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'HospitalDescriptionViewController'"

Comment: You have to declare HospitalData `struct` outside to your class HospitalViewController and not inside.

Comment: For the unwrapped error, use can use `if let` condition

Comment: Good to hear that!
Happy coding :)